# How to properly set prototype?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, prototype

I'm practicing an exercise in a book called [Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E7NCAYA).

The exercise in chapter 5 contains the following 4 questions:

> 1. Create an object called shape that has the type property and a   `getType()` method.
> 2. Define a `Triangle()` constructor function whose prototype is shape. Objects  created with `Triangle()` should have three own
>      properties—a, b, and c,  representing the lengths of the sides of a
>      triangle.
> 3. Add a new method to the prototype called `getPerimeter()`.
> 4. Test your implementation with the following code:
>
> .
>
> ```
>   var t = new Triangle(1, 2, 3);
>   t.constructor === Triangle;  // true
>   shape.isPrototypeOf(t);      // true
>   t.getPerimeter();            // 6
>   t.getType();                 // "triangle"
> ```

And this is my solution for the above questions:

```
var shape = {
    type: 'triangle',
    getType: function() {
        return this.type;
    }
};

function Triangle(a, b, c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

Triangle.prototype = shape;  // Maybe something goes wrong here

Triangle.prototype.getPerimeter = function() {
    return this.a + this.b + this.c;
}

// ======================================================
var t = new Triangle(1, 2, 3);              
console.log(t.constructor === Triangle);  // false
console.log(shape.isPrototypeOf(t));      // true
console.log(t.getPerimeter());            // 6
console.log(t.getType());                 // triangle
```

Why does `console.log(t.constructor === Triangle);` output `false` as the result?

I've tried removing `console.log(t.constructor === Triangle);`, which makes `t.constructor === Triangle` equals `true`, but results in `TypeError: t.getType is not a function` error.

How can I make my execution results the same as the answers provided by this book?

Comment: Try to use two `console.log` like this:
`console.log(t.constructor)`
`console.log(Triangle)`
and see the difference between the two outputs

Comment: `console.log(t.constructor)` outputs `[Function: Object]` while `console.log(Triangle)` outputs `[Function: Triangle]`.

Comment: They are different. That's why `t.constructor === Triangle` equals false.

Comment: I think that a better assertion would be: `console.log(typeof t === "Triangle")` since `t` is of type `Triangle` but `t.constructor` is just a "common" javascript function returning an object (i might be wrong about this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

`Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;`

after

`Triangle.prototype = shape;`

solves my problem.

In chapter 6 page 173, the book says

> Overwriting the prototype has side effects on the constructor property. Therefore, it's a good idea to reset the constructor after inheriting

Answer (score 0):

```js
Shape = {
  type: 'Shape',
  getType: function (){ return this.type;}
}

function Triangle( a, b, c){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.type = 'Triangle';
}

Triangle.prototype = Shape; 

Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;

Triangle.prototype.getPerimeter = function (){
  console.log('Get Perimeter');
  return this.a + this.b + this.c;
  
}

var t = new Triangle(1,2,3);
console.log(t.constructor === Triangle);
console.log(Shape.isPrototypeOf(t));      
console.log(t.getPerimeter());            
console.log(t.getType());
```

Assign Shap object to Triangle.prototype and then overwrite constructor with Triangle will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Shape() {
  type = "Shape";
 
}

Shape.prototype.getType = function() {
    return "Mi tipo es " + this.type;
  }

function Triangle(a, b, c) {
  Shape.call(this)
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
  this.type = "Triangle";
}

Triangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

Triangle.prototype.constructor = Triangle;

Triangle.prototype.getPerimeter = function() {
  return this.a + this.b + this.c;
}

var t = new Triangle(1, 2, 3);
console.log(t instanceof Triangle);
console.log(Shape.prototype.isPrototypeOf(t));
t.getPerimeter();
t.getType();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).